Failed to install platform-tools
Im in mac and having issue running
** cargo build-sbf --force-tools-install
[2024-11-12T20:08:10.629521000Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to install platform-tools: HTTP status client error (404 Not Found) for url (https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.42/platform-tools-osx-x86_64.tar.bz2)**
its going to github url thats not even there how do i fix it
thank you
solana-cli 2.0.16

I also had the same issue a few days ago and I spent a lot of time figuring it out and in order to fix it I downgraded my solana-cli to 1.18.21 during the build and then updated it back. You can change the version with:
solana-install init <VERSION>

And after you finish the build then update it back
agave-install update


To add some more information, there are no longer published compiler releases for x86 processors running OSX, since most Macs use aarch64 nowadays.
You can, however, build the compiler yourself following the steps at https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools?tab=readme-ov-file#building
More information at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/3566


I also had the same issue a few days ago and I spent a lot of time
figuring it out and in order to fix it I downgraded my solana-cli to
1.18.21 during the build and then updated it back. You can change the version with:
solana-install init  And after you finish the build then
update it back
agave-install update

solana-install init 1.18.21 didn't work for me,
I used
agave-install init 1.18.21
